# Camera only working with deprecated legacy option

Tags: python, picamera

I have a camera module connected to my Pi 3B+. I have downloaded the very latest raspberry Pi OS (called bullseye) which does not support the old. legacy camera stack. You don't even have to enable the camera in config any more, it should now be automatic.

The red light on the camera goes on but I can't execute the `raspistill` command, since it's deprecated. The new command is supposed to be `libcamera-hello` but that generates a huge list of errors, starting with `libEGL warning DRI2 failed to authenticate`

Also, in python, PiCamera does not work and suggests running `sudo raspi-config` to enable the legacy camera.

Should I just enable the legacy camera system again in config? It gives a warning that it's deprecated and will not be supported in the future...

Comment: use what works.  make stuff work if nothing else does... or if you have time

Comment: I can't understand why they release a OS where the camera doesn't work. Didn't they test it? Is python not important? Very weird.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue getting an all-sky software running under Bullseye. I think you need to ensure that the legacy camera software is DISABLED using raspi-config then reboot.

I suspect the legacy software is grabbing the camera interface and the new camera software in Bullseye cannot connect to it.

Comment: I rebooted many times in all kinds of configurations. But since python simply doesn't work at all with the new system, my only choice is to use the old system. Very strange!